# Gelila - where to you place the Yad?

Tags: minhag

Gelila - I was taught that when you do **Gelila** for a Sefer Torah, the Yad should be placed on the **Beraishit etz chayim (right side)**; I was recently asked if there is a source for this; I have been unable to find a source. Is anybody aware of a source?

Comment: Why not hanging from both?

Comment: looking for a source - a prior rabbi told us that it should be on the beraishit side - looking for a source or maybe there is no source and the Rabbi made it up...

Comment: I don't think the yad has any halachic significance beyond as an ornament. So which side should not matter. Maybe there is some sort of kabbalistic rationale.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!